# View with input parameters

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say that I have a view with the following structure (and sample data):

```
Sample_Name     Sample_Date         Sample_ID
John            01-01-2015          453
Jacob           10-10-2016          777
Jingle          11-11-2017          888
Heimer          12-12-2018          999
Schmidt         07-07-2019          333
```

If someone specifies the year (i.e. '2019'), I want to return that year and the year prior to it. So the following data set would return:

```
Sample_Name     Sample_Date         Sample_ID
Heimer          12-12-2018          999
Schmidt         07-07-2019          333
```

Is there any way for me to create the view with input parameters (similar to a function), where the user can specify what date they are looking for? Wen the date is specified, the view should return data from that year and the year prior to it. I know with functions you can do something similar but according to my google search, this isn't possible in Oracle :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense.

A view is just a stored query. If you want to fetch certain data from it, use a `where` clause, e.g.

```
select sample_name, sample_date, sample_id
from your_view
where extract (year from sample_date) >= :par_year - 1;
```

(where you'd enter `2019` into `:par_year`, when prompted) (`:` might need to be replaced by `&`, depending on a tool you use).